# PHP Contact Us Form Sending on Page Reload

Tags: php, html, forms, email, contact-form

I am fairly new at PHP and am trying to build out a simple contact us for my website. I have the form sending, but for some reason, it is also sending a blank message every time I reload the page. I have posted a bit of the form below.

Any help here / any tips you can offer would be appreciated.

```
   <?php

    $name_error = "";
    $name = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
            $name_error = "Whoops! Please enter your full name";
        } else {
            $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);

            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                $name_error = "Whoops! Only letters and white spaces are allowed in a name";
            }
        }

    if ($name_error == ''){
        $message_body = '';
        unset($_POST['submit']);
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
            $message_body .= "$key: $value\n";
        }   

        $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'Contact Us Form Submission';

        if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body )){
            $success = "Your message has been sent. A representative will be in contact with you shortly.";
            $name = $email = $phone = $message = $inquiry = $hear = $success = '';
        }
    }   
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

Comment: you need to wrap the post check around the whole sending code, it currently closes to early .. actually its not closed in the above code at all

Comment: Stop copying code from w3sh…, especially that clueless `test_input()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your "mail" logic needs to sit within the server request method, an easy fix would be to duplicate your if logic to be wrapped around your mailing logic. i.e.

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
  if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body )){
    $success = "Your message has been sent. A representative will be in contact with you shortly.";
    $name = $email = $phone = $message = $inquiry = $hear = $success = '';
  }
}
```

Of course, you may as well just remove your current if statements closing bracket, and chuck it at the end of your code (as theres no need to break the if statement so early)

i.e.

```
<?php

$name_error = "";
$name = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
        $name_error = "Whoops! Please enter your full name";
    } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);

        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
            $name_error = "Whoops! Only letters and white spaces are allowed in a name";
        }
    }

if ($name_error == ''){
    $message_body = '';
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        $message_body .= "$key: $value\n";
    }   

    $to = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Contact Us Form Submission';

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body )){
        $success = "Your message has been sent. A representative will be in contact with you shortly.";
        $name = $email = $phone = $message = $inquiry = $hear = $success = '';
    }
}

// <--- ADD CLOSING BRACKET HERE

function test_input($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```